# Excel VBA Detect once ALL the cells in a range have changed

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm looking to detect and run a certain function in VBA once all the cells in range G4:G7 have changed. I've seen many posts detecting when ONE of the cells in range have changed, whereas I want to detect once ALL of them have changed. Thanks! Hopefully someone can help me, I'm in quite a pickle.

Comment: Changed ever, since a particular point? You could keep track on a separate worksheet perhaps.

Comment: How are they changing? Do they contain values, or formulas?

Comment: They contain values.

Comment: f I understand what you're asking, you could save the initial contents of the cells in question (e.g. in the Workbook_Open event handler, depending on what you mean by "initial"), then after any cell in the range changes, check if all have changed from their initial state.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks joe

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please. It must be copied in the sheet module, like its `Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static arrChng As Variant, boolOver As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range, ans As VbMsgBoxResult

    Set rng = Range("G4:G7") 'the range can be extended down ("G4:G10", for instance)
                             'without other code modifications..
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        If IsEmpty(arrChng) Then
            arrChng = rng.Value
        End If
        If boolOver Then
                ans = MsgBox("All values in range """ & rng.address & """ have been changed!" & _
                   vbCrLf & "The input value will be reversed..." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                   "Would you like to reset the range?", vbYesNo, "No changes allowed")
                   If ans = vbYes Then arrChng = Empty: boolOver = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False
              Application.Undo
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        arrChng(Target.row - (rng.row - 1), 1) = "Changed"
        If UBound(Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arrChng, 0, 1)), _
                                        "Changed", True)) = UBound(arrChng, 1) - 1 Then
            boolOver = True
            MsgBox "All values in range """ & rng.address & """ have been changed!" & vbCrLf & _
                   "No more changes allowed.", vbInformation, "No changes allowed"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It will warn when the last cell has been changed and at the next changing attempt it works again, but reversing the input to the previous cell value, asking for reset, too.